# Azure ServiceBus SAS in Node.js SDK

Tags: node.js, azure, servicebus

Is there a way to use SAS authentication for Azure ServiceBus in Azure Node.js SDK? Their home page still suggests using AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE and the AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY environment variables, which is the default user with all rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection strings is the way to go:

var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService('Endpoint=sb://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=mysharedkey')

Hope it helps,
Andre

Comment: André, have you actually tested it? I saw a message in some MS blog that SAS only works with .NET SDK for now, it is not supported even in Java SDK.

Comment: I used service bus connection string but after sometime it started giving me Token Expired (401) error.

Comment: doesn't work with shared access signature (sas) token with this format: SharedAccessSignature sig=<signature-string>&se=<expiry>&skn=<keyName>&sr=<URL-encoded-resourceURI>