# How to connect to an Azure Service Bus subscription with the Node.js SDK using SAS Keys?

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Is there a way to connect to an Azure Service Bus Subscription using a Shared Access Signature Key in the Node.js SDK? We want to use the SAS Key to read the messages from the subscription.

There is something a about [SAS](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-sb/latest/SharedAccessSignature.html) in the [documentation](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-sb/latest/) but nothing concrete.

I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you seen this [stack over flow answer from a while back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089550/azure-servicebus-sas-in-node-js-sdk) ?

Comment: I have seen it, but that was in 2014, I thought the SDK changed a bit since then.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Access Signatures (SAS) are the primary security mechanism for Service Bus messaging. Normally, SAS tokens for Service Bus publishers are created with only sending and receiving privileges on a specific queue or topic. So you'd need to use the connection string to connect to an Azure Service Bus namespace instead.

This package allows you to easily generate a Shared Access Signature: https://github.com/mitchdenny/shared-access-signature.

About how to send a message to a Service Bus queue or topic using a SAS token via REST API, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue.

For more information about working with SAS, see [Shared Access Signature Authentication with Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas).

Comment: We'll be generating sas keys in our backend. We thought of using the Node.js SDK on the client side for reading messages. That's why I asked if there is a way of using the Node SDK for reading messages with SAS keys. We're switching to using the REST API to read the messages in node using 'https' model.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

Understood but without creating an instance , you wont be able to do anything with regard to service bus operations - these include being able to read messages from the subscription no ?

So in theory your code should look something like this :

```
var serviceBusConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://somens.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=mykey";

var retryOperations = new azure.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter();
var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService(serviceBusConnectionString).withFilter(retryOperations);

serviceBusService.receiveSubscriptionMessage('MyTopic', 'LowMessages', function(error, receivedMessage){
    if(!error){
        // Message received and deleted
        console.log(receivedMessage);
    }
});
```

[More info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions)

*Original*:

Check this one out as well [followup stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516009/azure-servicebus-token-expired/29585706#29585706) , Combined these two links should sort you out ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't want to create a Service Bus instance with the connection string. I want to create a Service Bus instance for reading messages from a Subscription using a SAS key.

Comment: We tried that with no successful results unfortunately.

Comment: Could you post some sample code - so we can see what you are trying to achieve ?